# fullPage = true; on CKEditor being ignored by some browsers

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

We are using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (CKEditor 3.6.4 for ASP.NET) on our intranet site, developed in ASP.NET and hosted on IIS 7.5

The editor has to support full HTML; including `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

To do this we have set the `fullPage = true;` property in the `config.js` file as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.fullPage)

Now this works perfectly fine on all browsers (FireFox/Chrome/I.E for our needs) from my development version; VS2010 with the development server.

However, when running on IIS it only works on I.E. The editor strips HTML and wraps up in `<p>` tags for FireFox and Chrome.

I have tried disabling caching for the `.js` files on IIS though this hasn't helped.

I have checked the HTTP return for the `config.js` and it returns an HTTP 304; though the response content is all there, including the `fullPage = true;` setting.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue? To clarify, the editor under FireFox and Chrome seems to ignore the `fullPage=true;` flag.